# How to show nodes and users in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view where I show nodes of content type, with some filters exposed .
But , I wish that these filters also show results of users (based on their username and a field of them).

### Exposed Filters (nodes):

- Title node (TextField)
- Body (TextField)
- Field Category (Dropdown)

### Exposed Filters for Users (desired):

- Username (TextField)
- Field Category (Dropdown)

In this case , I wish that the Title_Node and Username are the same TextField(Is it posible). And the field_category serve to search both.

Is it posible to show content types and users in a views in Drupal 7 with filters exposed?

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say you want the Title_Node and Username are the same TextField" do you mean you want the Username to show next to the Title node, so "Node Title by Dvex"?

Comment: @longboardnode I mean, if I put a text in the text field , do the search by the title_node first and then the username . It's like combining filters into one.

Comment: See this post on drupal.org [https://www.drupal.org/node/451000][1]   Normally, once you have added the fields to your filters, click on Add Filter, then select Global: Combine Filters. BUT in your case since you want to search the username (which is an entity reference, not a text field) then I don't think you'd be able to combine them without creating some custom module and manipulating the search yourself.